# Is it possible to recover overwritten files from another operating System on the current operating system?

Tags: ubuntu, files, windows, data-recovery, system-recovery

On my PC I had 2 operating sytems (ubuntu and windows) and for about 5 days I wanted to reinstall my Windows OS because of some bugs but instead of installing it on the partition where my old version of windows is I have installed it on the partitions where my Ubuntu OS was 
so my question is, is it possible to recover some files which I saved on the Ubuntu ? because I ve already tried some softwares but until now I still have no result and I really need these files

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have over-written your Ubuntu partition with a Windows reinstallation, chances of recovering files are pretty low.

With :

- A LOT of time
- a pretty large storage space on another drive
- another PC where you can plug your hard drive (stop writing on your Windows/Ubuntu drive NOW!!!)
- an indecent amount of luck (sorry)

you *may* recover some files with dedicated tools. I had results with [Scalpel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scalpel) running on Debian (there are other softwares available, both for Windows and Linux).

Scalpel (and possibly others) works by looking for "file signature" on the drive surface, which means it helps if you instruct it what to look for : JPEGs, OpenOffice files, ...

What may increase your chances too is the amount of data before / after the reinstallation : if there were -for instance- 1TB of data and you only wrote 100GB, some areas of the disk *may* have been untouched.

Comment: Thank you so much for your honest answer time is not a problem for and I am also aware of the possibilities that I may not find this file anymore but i still want to try it if it could save my worktime 
So I have 1TB spacedisk which I divided to 2 partitions and both of these are only using 200go space. Like you said i still have a kind of chance to retrieve my file
the data what I m looking for is a text document (.odf file) and i tried to recover it using Stellar (with stellar i ve not found any .odf data so i do not know if it"s the software or if the file is gone forever )